# Boat options from To'opua to Vaitape

Tags: ferries, timetables, tahiti

We are going to stay at the Conrad Bora Bora on To'opua island in Tahiti. Some of the restaurants we would like to visit are on next door Vaitape island.

The hotel has boat service "for a fee," per their website. What is the fee for a boat provided by the hotel? Are there regular ferries or boats that travel between To'opua and Vaitape, and if so how much do they cost?

Comment: Have you asked the hotel?